# Three layers of If-Then case statements in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am working on an excel document to understand product feature violations based on customer spend level (i.e. the more they spend, the more choice of features they are presented to choose from. Conversely, the less they spend, the less choices they have to choose from.

There are about 7 variables that we use to measure products. For each of those variables, there are multiple options within each variable. For example, one feature could be color and the variables of that color feature could be black, white, red, yellow etc.

Based on spend level by customers, they can or cannot be allowed to have certain options from those variables. For example:

- customer spending 10K can have a black product, but no other colors
- customer spending 20K can have a blue product or black product but not a red product
- customer spending 30K can have a black, blue or red product

So if there is an entry where a customer spending 10K and has a blue product, I would like it to be "flagged" in some way, with the intention of knowing how many "violations" are happening for a range in time (i.e. December 2018).

I would need a way to create an if-then statement that first searches for spend, then can reference what is / is not allowed in that spend, then determine if it is violating those rules.

Comment: Sounds like an `IF` statement with a `VLOOKUP` to see the spend level associated with a product colour would do the job. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Haven't done anything yet, but was thinking of going that route. Just so I understand correctly - I would use the IF statement to determine the spend level (there are 4 spend levels in total), then once the spend level is determined refer to a vlookup on a table that lists out each of the allowable features?

Comment: The exact opposite: use the `VLOOKUP` to determine the spend level based on the product colour, then the `IF` to compare with the actual spend level. See my answer

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways you can approach this. You could define the allowed colours for each range of prices in some hidden helper worksheet, and then reference that. Grab the customer's spend, check match the column, then check if their selected option exists in that column. If it doesn't, flag the cell -- highlight it or whatever you want you do.

```sh
+-------+-------+-------+
| 19999 | 29999 | 39999 |
+-------+-------+-------+
| black | black | black |
|       | blue  | blue  |
|       |       | red   |
+-------+-------+-------+
```

You could also approach this purely in VBA by using dictionaries to store these permitted options. Then just iterate over the dictionary keys, comparing the customers spend, to find the appropriate dictionary store. Once you've found your match, take the value, split it into an array, then compare if their chosen option, is a valid one for that spend range.

```vb
Dim options As Dictionary
Set options = New Dictionary
options.Add "19999", "black"
options.Add "29999", "black,blue"
options.Add "39999", "black,blue,red"

For Each spend In options.Keys
    'if customer spend is less than the max (defined here as the key)
    'then grab the value, and split it into an array
    allowedChoices = Split(options.Item(spend ), ",")

    ' if the customers selected choice is in the array of allowed choices
    If IsInArray(<the_users_choice>, allowedChoices) Then
        'flag whatever, however
    End If
Next spend
```

These are a couple of options you could use to approach this. Get creative -- goodluck.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Column A has the spending amount, and B the color.

This formula on any other column:

```
=IF(A2>=30000,IF(OR(B2="Black",B2="Blue",B2="Red"),"OK","FLAG"),IF(A2>=20000,IF(OR(B2="Black",B2="Blue"),"OK","FLAG"),IF(A2>=10000,IF(B2="Black","OK","FLAG"),"Less than 10000")))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create a lookup table to determine the spend levels:

[image]

Then use the following formula to determine if a customer should be flagged:

```
=IF(VLOOKUP(B2,J$2:K$4,2)>A2,"flagged","")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I went with a similar approach, but instead of the vlookup I did a combination of IF + SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(TABLE NAME)